Is there another way of finding the eigenvectors?
In the following exercise I am asked to find the orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $P^tFP$ is in normal form (diagonal?). Where $$F=\frac{1}{4}\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{3} & \sqrt{3} & 3 & -1 \\\ \sqrt{3} & \sqrt{3} & -1 & 3 \\\ 1 & -3 & \sqrt{3} & \sqrt{3} \\\ -3 & 1 & \sqrt{3} & \sqrt{3} \end{bmatrix}$$ The eigenvalues I obtained are $1, -1, e^{\pi/6i}, e^{-\pi/6i}$ and in order to finding the eigenvector I know I need to solve the system $$(F-I\lambda)\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$$ However, I think that the expressions I am obtaining are too complicated and maybe there are other ways of finding the eigenvectors, but I cannot find them.
